# Reusable Data Mining Code?

Tags: algorithm, data-mining

I was assigned an extra credit project where I'm given a set of data and told to run data mining algorithms on them. (Supposed to choose two of  Apriori, PART, RIPPER, and J48).

We're told to reuse code for the algorithm implementation of this project, but the only code I can find is example code and can't easily be run on the data set given to us for the project. Does anybody know of premade java data mining algorithms that I can use on my data?

Comment: you have to modify your dataset to the format algorithm supprots....

Comment: [DMTL](http://dmtl.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I really struggle to understand how these algorithms work. I'm not sure what I should be changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by looking at http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/. Websearches suggest that it supports the first two options I checked, Apriori and J48. There is quite reasonable Java source code, but also a GUI interface. You may be able to do what you need just by writing code to produce stuff in a format Weka can read and then working within the Weka GUI.